# Android - Tile Image Button

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, imagebutton

I am trying to tile image buttons to look like this in Android :

[image: Tile Image Buttons]
.

To achieve this I tried it using `RelativeLayout`, without any success.

The XML layout that I used is as the following :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ibutton1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"></ImageButton>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ibutton2" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/ibutton1"  
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"></ImageButton>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ibutton3" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ibutton1" 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"></ImageButton>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ibutton4" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ibutton2" 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"></ImageButton>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Additional question : is there a way to perform this programmatically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `GridView`, `GridLayout` and [`DashboardLayout`](https://gist.github.com/882650) come to mind. All work fine for adding items dynamically, even the `RelativeLayout` you've come up with yourself, although I'd say the `GridView` has some benefits if you often need to change/update the items as you go. There is not really a 'correct' way to approach this - you should probably use what best suits your needs and you feel comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

did you try with LinearLayout and after use the ImageButton Properties?
In ImageButton's Properties there is Margin --> Left,Top etc here you can put the required distance from the objects.

I used this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCadO2NgzD0